# Skin effect - resistance changes during DC/AC variation

Tags: resistance, power-electronics, cables, skin-effect

I have a question about skin effect, skin depth to be exact.

Consider an AC system and a wire in it. Skin **depth** is, let it be, 0.2 radius of it.
We know that if it was a DC system, it would spread the current evenly and then the resistance would be lower than in AC system (according to [image] - bigger surface "makes" lower resistance).

My question is - is it possible to tell exactly how many times did the resistance decrease (comparing DC with AC)?

Comment: There are plenty of examples if you google.

Comment: So is it just a ratio between two surfaces (pi*R^2 vs pi*R^2 - 0.8pi*R^2)? There won't be any other information, just value of skin depth and both AC and DC system.

Comment: There are ac resistance calculators on line and more often than not these will give formulas.

Comment: In reality, the wire will also show inductive behaviour, which will also increase the impedance with frequency. Noticeable skin effect normally occurs at much higher frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

In short - no, it can’t be done **exactly** :)

#### Why not?

The resistance accounts for all active power losses in the wire. The losses are a sum of different effects, some of which are modeled by theories (such as skin effect, magnetic hysteresis losses, eddy currents in conductors near the wire, the corona-effect, etc).
Other loss factors are usually not very well modelled in electrical engineering applications, and are usually just bunched together and just called *[excess losses](http://google.se/?q=excess%20losses%20iron)*. The excess losses are then estimated by some measurement at a specific operating point. Examples of excess losses: could be some capacitive (electrostatic) coupling with nearby conductors leading to moving currents, electromagnetic waves being emitted due to an antenna-like geometry, weird stuff with the magnetic domains on a molecular level, and so on.

#### Approximatively then

Wikipedia has a nice article about the skin effect, and with some approximation formula for how much the resistance will increase *due to the the skin effect only* (but maybe that was what you were asking for?) in round conductors.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

#### Next level

I can recommend Power System Analysis by Grainger, which can probably be borrowed at some technical library close to you, or maybe online? A lot of worked examples on different transmission line setups with different inductances etc. If you want the full truth about how skin depth is derived I would recommend Electromagnetic Fields by Wangsness. Prerequisite for both books is 1st year calculus at university level. (if any moderator thinks I sound like an ad, please edit this paragraph away)